# PySpark Structured Streaming Testing Support

Tags: pyspark

I have investigated a lot but couldn't get any help or resource on **how to test my pyspark Structured Streaming pipeline job** (ingesting from Kafka topics to S3) and how to build  Continuous Integration (CI)/Continuous Deployment (CD).

1. Is it possible to test (unit test, integration test) pyspark structured stream?
2. How to build  Continuous Integration (CI)/Continuous Deployment (CD)?

Comment: Have you already found an answer?

Comment: Yes. I have separated the E, T, L part of the code into functions and Unit test -  transformation function in isolation where my business logic is present. Then  for integration test I have used Docker to run kafka, spark and test end to end integration (read from Kafka, transform and write the output to AWS S3). I am using pytest. Leveraged @pytest.fixture to automatically create and teardown s3 buckets for the tests. @pytest.mark.parametrize() to pass the bucket name dynamically. Create a new kafka topic for each test, therefore test will be deterministic, as topics are persistent.

Answer (score -5):

1. Refer to https://bartoszgajda.com/2020/04/13/testing-spark-structured-streaming-using-memorystream/ - the code is in Scala but you should be able to convert to PySpark
2. Start with Jenkins (https://www.jenkins.io/)

Comment: I have seen MemoryStream, but its Scala one and I could not use that in pySpark. Have you used this in Pyspark?

Comment: Memory stream is supported in PySpark as per https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/streaming.html. You can specify 'memory' as format just as in Scala

Comment: @dipanjanb if MemoryStream is available in Python, could you please show an example of how you're going to import it in your Python code?